# why hbase is crashing

Tags: hbase, apache-zookeeper

hbase is started having some problems and started crashing. These are the errors in hbase logs before it shuts itself:

```
2015-08-19 19:13:33,453 WARN  [ctcprserver01,49413,1439902278935-HeapMemoryTunerChore] util.Sleeper: We slept 73458ms instead of 60000ms, this is likely due to a long garbage collecting pause and it's usually bad, see http://hbase.apache.org/book.html#trouble.rs.runtime.zkexpired
    "NonHeapMemoryUsage" : {
    "HeapMemoryUsage" : {
2015-08-19 19:13:35,646 INFO  [RS:0;ctcprserver01:49413] regionserver.HeapMemoryManager: Stoping HeapMemoryTuner chore.
2015-08-19 19:13:35,646 INFO  [ctcprserver01,49413,1439902278935-HeapMemoryTunerChore] regionserver.HeapMemoryManager$HeapMemoryTunerChore: ctcprserver01,49413,1439902278935-HeapMemoryTunerChore exiting
```

I have heap size configured to 100G as follows:

```
export HBASE_HEAPSIZE=100G
```

Is the hbase running out of heap memory? Any ideas how to address this?

Comment: why are you using 100gb heap? recommendation is below 20 gb heap.

Answer (score 0):

Large heap size may cause garbage collection to take longer then expected because the collector has to finalize and evict more objects from heap. When GC, for example MarkSweepCompact, is running it may cause other threads to sleep, causing Zookeeper to timeout clients.

[image]

It makes sense to monitor both invocation per minute as well as cpu % spent on collection for each collector in the JVM: